# Server did not response with a CredSSP token after step Step 1. TLS Handshake - actual ''

Tags: ansible

I'm struggling with pinging my managed node from my control node using

```
ansible --inventory ./inventory.yml -m win_ping all
```

I'm receiving the following response

```
myvm| UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "credssp: Server did not response with a CredSSP token after step Step 1. TLS Handshake - actual ''",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I used this command to setup WinRM:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"
$file = "$env:temp\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"

(New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $file)

powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File $file
```

my WinRM Listener looks like:

```
Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 10.111.1.30, 10.0.1.4, 127.0.0.1, ::1, fe80::5499:eaf2:efa9:aa53%5, fe80::8d52:ccbf:2551:3f2c%10

Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTPS
    Port = 5986
    Hostname = vmghostim
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint = 9b bd ac 47 85 0a 69 e2  76 23 3f 1d 15 c6 c6 ab61 83 bc 62
    ListeningOn = 10.111.1.30, 10.0.1.4, 127.0.0.1, ::1, fe80::5499:eaf2:efa9:aa53%5, fe80::8d52:ccbf:2551:3f2c%10
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try `-vvvv` to enable connection debugging

Comment: I dont see any errors there, it fails after `<myvm> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: admin on PORT 5986 TO myvm`

Comment: What version of Windows are you on?

Answer (score 2):

## CredSSP handshake error

You getting this error means, you are trying to use CredSSP over HTTPS connection, the problem can be that there is configured certificate thumbprint directly in winrm/config/services

```
class 'requests_credssp.exceptions.AuthenticationException'>("Server did not 
response with a CredSSP token after step Step 1. TLS Handshake - actual ''",)
```

### Execute this command to delete CertificateThumbprint value from the config/service.

```
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{CertificateThumbprint=""}'
```

The configuration of certificate thumbprint in the Listener should remain there.